# SOQL returning 0 rows

Tags: apex, trigger, soql

I've created a helper class and method which takes Trigger.new as parameter. The soql at a place is returning zero records despite a record is present.

```
public class CaseDispatcher {
public static Map<id,id> getCaseMap (List<Case> caseList)
{
    List<Case> listcase = new List<Case>();
    listcase = caseList;
    Map<Id, list<case>> caseMap = new Map<Id, list<case>>();
    list<user> creatorList = new list<user>();

    system.debug(listcase.size());

    for(case c:listcase)
    {                  
      if(caseMap.containsKey(c.createdbyId))
      {
        caseMap.get(c.createdbyId).add(c);  
      }
       else
      {
        caseMap.put(c.createdById, new list<case>{c});

      } 

    }        
    system.debug(caseMap.size());
    system.debug(caseMap.values().size());

    creatorList = [SELECT id from user where id in :caseMap.keySet()];
    system.debug(creatorList.size());
```

`caseMap.size()` returns 1 but the  SOQL is returning zero records.
Thus `creatorList` is empty

Comment: can you remove unnecessary codes, specially variable declarations sections and also is this helper class method is called before or after trigger insert/update not specified

Comment: @SantanuBoral I haven't pasted the whole class, so it should be ok

Comment: caseMap.get(c.createdbyId).add(c);   logic is not clear

Comment: The value of `CreatedById` is null in a `before insert` context.

Comment: @SantanuBoral I'm building a map of type Map<Id, list<case>>

Comment: @AdrianLarson but the caseMap is returning the size of 1

Comment: Can you print the CaseMap.keySet() and try to run the same query in Dev Console. is that returning 1 row in Dev console?

Comment: The one key can be null...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "audit fields" (CreatedDate, LastModifiedDate, CreatedById, and LastModifiedById) are all *null* during a BeforeInsert trigger. Use UserInfo.getUserId() to find out who's creating the record in a BeforeInsert trigger, or use AfterInsert instead (depends on what you're trying to do).

Comment: @Bennie to support this, and Adrian's comments, you can do a System.debug(caseMap) instead of System.debug(caseMap.size()). It will clearly show you what is the value in the map's keyset.